# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, pytorch

I try to check if torch have been properly installed by script:

```
    import torch
    print(torch.__version__)
```

and have the result:
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '**version**'

I've checked if torch is installed in my venv by:

```
    pip freeze
```

and it is installed(I tried to install as via conda as via pip as suggested at https://pytorch.org/):

- torch==1.7.1+cu110
- torchaudio==0.7.2
- torchvision==0.8.2+cu110

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU Geforce RTX 3070
- Driver version 460.39
- Cuda Toolkit V11.0.194
- Cudnn V8.0.5.39
- Python V3.6.9

Do not understand what's the problem

Comment: Don't name your file `torch.py` this will cause your local script to shadow the module named `torch`. Instead of importing the pytorch module you are importing your local `torch.py` (/home/evgeniy/cnn/torch.py).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, it was related to a a poorly installed version of torch.

Just `pip uninstall torch` and `pip install torch==2.0.0+cu117` worked for me.

It should also work for another torch version.

Comment: I also got the same weird error due to a bad installation of torch. The error message did not seem to make sense with the behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch has a sub-module called version and from that you can say,
`torch.version.__version__`

Comment: tried:import torch
print(torch.version.__version__) the output is the same:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torch.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/evgeniy/cnn/torch.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(torch.version.__version__) 
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'

Comment: Humph. Note taken

Comment: When run from terminal it's ok

Comment: I have this work form a Jupyter notebook, but not when run directly in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by @jodag:

Don't name your file torch.py this will cause your local script to shadow the module named torch. Instead of importing the pytorch module you are importing your local torch.py (/home/evgeniy/cnn/torch.py).